# doctrine silently fails to delete entities on M side of 1:M

Tags: php, doctrine-orm, zf3

I am beginning to suspect that this doesn't work because in my use case it just doesn't -- as opposed to me missing something -- but I have to consult your expertise to make sure, and to see if anyone can suggesta workaround.

I have a Many-to-Many situation that I am implementing with an association class, so we have one-to-many/many-to-one associations between the 3 participating classes. There is an Interpreter entity representing a person, and a Language entity representing a spoken language (actually a working language pair, but one half of the pair is understood to be English in this anglocentric application). An Interpreter can have multiple languages, and a Language is among the working languages of multiple interpreters. We need to manage other attributes of the interpreter-language, hence the InterpreterLanguage class.

When I call `$interpreter->removeInterpreterLanguage($interpreterLanguage);` followed by `$entityManager->flush()`, the in-memory Interpreter entity has one fewer elements in its `$interpreterLanguages` collection as you would expect, and there is no error or Exception thrown, but in the database here's what happens: *nothing*.

I have tried this in an MVC context, with ZendFramework 3 and a bound `Zend\Form\Form` with fieldsets, and when that drove me nuts I wrote a CLI script to try to examine the problem -- same result. Maybe it's worth noting that for updating scalar properties it's working fine.

I apologize for not including a link to the discussion of this issue that I read earlier -- can't find it now, for some reason. But I recall someone saying that it just doesn't work because Doctrine sees the M:1 on the other side, and therefore won't delete, and you have to say `$entityManager->remove($object)` to get it done. My experimental CLI script appears to confirm this. Nevertheless, I'd like to rule out the possibility that I am doing something wrong.

Any ideas? Suggestions for solving?

So here's my Language entity:

```
/** module/InterpretersOffice/src/Entity/Language.php */

namespace InterpretersOffice\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Zend\Form\Annotation;
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection;

/**
 * Entity class representing a language used by an Interpreter.
 *
 * @Annotation\Name("language")
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="InterpretersOffice\Entity\Repository\LanguageRepository")
 * @ORM\Table(name="languages",uniqueConstraints={@ORM\UniqueConstraint(name="unique_language",columns={"name"})})
 */
class Language
{
    /**
     * entity id.
     *     
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue @ORM\Column(type="smallint",options={"unsigned":true})
     */
    protected $id;

    /**
     * name of the language.
     *
     * @ORM\Column(type="string",length=50,nullable=false)
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $name;

    /**
     * comments.
     *
     * @ORM\Column(type="string",length=300,nullable=false,options={"default":""})
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $comments = '';

    /**
     *
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="InterpreterLanguage",mappedBy="language")
     */
    protected $interpreterLanguages;

    /**
     * constructor
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->interpreterLanguages = new ArrayCollection();
    }
    // setters and getters omitted for brevity

}
```

Here is the Interpreter entity:

```
<?php
/** module/InterpretersOffice/src/Entity/Interpreter.php */

namespace InterpretersOffice\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection;
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection;

/**
 * Entity representing an Interpreter.
 *
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="InterpretersOffice\Entity\Repository\InterpreterRepository")
 * @ORM\Table(name="interpreters")
 */
class Interpreter extends Person
{
    /**
     * entity id.
     *
     * @ORM\Id @ORM\GeneratedValue @ORM\Column(type="smallint",options={"unsigned":true})
     */
    protected $id;

    /**
     * phone number.
     *
     * @ORM\Column(type="string",length=16,nullable=true)
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $phone;

    /**
     * date of birth.
     *
     * @ORM\Column(type="date",nullable=true)
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $dob;

    /**
     * working languages.
     *
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="InterpreterLanguage",mappedBy="interpreter", cascade={"persist", "remove"})
     * 
     *
     * @var ArrayCollection of InterpreterLanguage
     */
    protected $interpreterLanguages;

    /**
     * Constructor.
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->interpreterLanguages = new ArrayCollection();
    }

    // some boring setters and getters omitted.... 

    /**
     * Add interpreterLanguage.
     *
     * @param InterpreterLanguage $interpreterLanguage
     *
     * @return Interpreter
     */
    public function addInterpreterLanguage(InterpreterLanguage $interpreterLanguage)
    {
        $this->interpreterLanguages->add($interpreterLanguage);
        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Remove interpreterLanguage.
     *
     * @param \InterpretersOffice\Entity\InterpreterLanguage $interpreterLanguage
     *
     * @return Interpreter
     */
    public function removeInterpreterLanguage(InterpreterLanguage $interpreterLanguage)
    {       

        $this->interpreterLanguages->removeElement($interpreterLanguage);
        //$interpreterLanguage->setInterpreter(null)->setLanguage(null);
        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get interpreterLanguages.
     *
     * @return \Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection
     */
    public function getInterpreterLanguages()
    {
        return $this->interpreterLanguages;
    }

    /*
     because "AllowRemove strategy for DoctrineModule hydrator requires both addInterpreterLanguages and  removeInterpreterLanguages to be defined in InterpretersOffice\Entity\Interpreter entity domain code, but one or both 
     [seemed] to be missing"
     */


    public function addInterpreterLanguages(Collection $interpreterLanguages)
    {
        foreach ($interpreterLanguages as $interpreterLanguage) {

            $interpreterLanguage->setInterpreter($this);
            $this->interpreterLanguages->add($interpreterLanguage);
        }
    }

    public function removeInterpreterLanguages(Collection $interpreterLanguages)
    {
        foreach ($interpreterLanguages as $interpreterLanguage) {

            $this->interpreterLanguages->removeElement($interpreterLanguage);

        }
    }

}
```

and the association class:

```
/** module/InterpretersOffice/src/Entity/InterpreterLanguage.php  */

namespace InterpretersOffice\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * Entity representing an Interpreter's Language.
 *
 * Technically, it is a language *pair*, but in this system it is understood that
 * the other language of the pair is English. There is a many-to-many relationship
 * between interpreters and languages. But because there is also metadata to record
 * about the language (federal certification), it is implemented as a Many-To-One
 * relationship on either side.
 *
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ORM\Table(name="interpreters_languages")
 */
class InterpreterLanguage
{
    /**
     * constructor.
     *
     * @param Interpreter $interpreter
     * @param Language    $language
     *
     * @todo a lifecycle callback to ensure certified languages have a boolean
     * $federalCertification set
     */
    public function __construct(
        Interpreter $interpreter = null,
        Language $language = null
    ) {
        if ($interpreter) {
            $this->setInterpreter($interpreter);
        }
        if ($language) {
            $this->setLanguage($language);
        }
    }

    /**
     * The Interpreter who works in this language.
     *
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Interpreter",inversedBy="interpreterLanguages")
     * @ORM\Id
     *
     * @var Interpreter
     */
    protected $interpreter;

    /**
     * The language in which this interpreter works.
     *
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Language",inversedBy="interpreterLanguages")
     * @ORM\Id
     *
     * @var Language
     */
    protected $language;

    /**
     * Whether the Interpreter holds federal court interpreter certification in this language.
     *
     * The only certified languages in the US District Court system are Spanish,
     * Navajo and Haitian Creole. Of these, only the Spanish certification
     * program is active. This field should be a boolean for the certified
     * languages and null for everything else.
     *
     * @link http://www.uscourts.gov/services-forms/federal-court-interpreters/federal-court-interpreter-certification-examination the federal court certification program
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="federal_certification",type="boolean",nullable=true)
     *
     * @var bool
     */
    protected $federalCertification;

    /**
     * Set interpreter.
     *
     * @param \InterpretersOffice\Entity\Interpreter $interpreter
     *
     * @return InterpreterLanguage
     */
    public function setInterpreter(Interpreter $interpreter = null)
    {
        $this->interpreter = $interpreter;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get interpreter.
     *
     * @return Interpreter
     */
    public function getInterpreter()
    {
        return $this->interpreter;
    }

    /**
     * Set language.
     *
     * @param Language $language
     *
     * @return InterpreterLanguage
     */
    public function setLanguage(Language $language = null)
    {
        $this->language = $language;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get language.
     *
     * @return Language
     */
    public function getLanguage()
    {
        return $this->language;
    }

    /**
     * Set federalCertification.
     *
     * @param bool $federalCertification
     *
     * @return InterpreterLanguage
     */
    public function setFederalCertification($federalCertification)
    {
        $this->federalCertification = $federalCertification;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get federalCertification.
     *
     * @return bool
     */
    public function getFederalCertification()
    {
        return $this->federalCertification;
    }
}
```

For brevity's sake, I will leave out the code for the Form and the Fieldset classes -- they do seem to be working fine (look tasteful, too. Thank you Bootstrap). I load the form, I remove one of the InterpreterLanguages and submit... Here's the controller action:

```
/**
 * updates an Interpreter entity.
 */
public function editAction()
{
    $viewModel = (new ViewModel())
            ->setTemplate('interpreters-office/admin/interpreters/form.phtml')
            ->setVariable('title', 'edit an interpreter');
    $id = $this->params()->fromRoute('id');

    $entity = $this->entityManager->find('InterpretersOffice\Entity\Interpreter', $id);
    if (!$entity) {
        return $viewModel->setVariables(['errorMessage' => "interpreter with id $id not found"]);
    }
    $form = new InterpreterForm($this->entityManager, ['action' => 'update']);
    $form->bind($entity);
    $viewModel->setVariables(['form' => $form, 'id' => $id ]);

    $request = $this->getRequest();
    if ($request->isPost()) {
        $form->setData($request->getPost());
        if (!$form->isValid()) {
            return $viewModel;
        }
        $this->entityManager->flush();
        $this->flashMessenger()
              ->addSuccessMessage(sprintf(
                  'The interpreter <strong>%s %s</strong> has been updated.',
                  $entity->getFirstname(),
                  $entity->getLastname()
              ));
        // dump the entity and see how it looksa after update
        echo "NOT redirecting. entity:<pre>";
        \Doctrine\Common\Util\Debug::dump($entity); echo "</pre>";
        //$this->redirect()->toRoute('interpreters');
    } else { 
        // dump the entity fresh from the database
        echo "loaded:<pre> "; \Doctrine\Common\Util\Debug::dump($entity);echo "</pre>";}

    return $viewModel;
}
```

Again, the data looks right as it's dumped to the screen, but you reload the form and the collection has as many elements as it did before.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Interpreter.php, orphanRemoval=true !!

```
/**
 * working languages.
 *
 * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="InterpreterLanguage",mappedBy="interpreter", 
 * cascade={"persist", "remove"},orphanRemoval=true)
 *
 * @var ArrayCollection of InterpreterLanguage
 */
protected $interpreterLanguages;
```

Comment: I should be ashamed of the question because I asked the very same thing a few months earlier, and forgot, and failed to find it before posting. That's what you get when you're 58 years old. You'll see, my young friends! :-)